# Mouse over effect with jQuery in richfaces datatable and datascroller combo

Tags: jquery, richfaces

I'm problem with defining a mouse over effect for my datatables.
I have

```
<a4j:form>
    <rich:dataTable id="dataTable"> ... </rich:dataTable>
    <rich:datascroller id="dataScroller" for="dataTable" />
</a4j:form>

<rich:jQuery selector="#dataTable tr" query="mouseover(function(){jQuery(this).addClass('active-row')})"/>
<rich:jQuery selector="#dataTable tr" query="mouseout(function(){jQuery(this).removeClass('active-row')})"/>
```

which are working fine on the very first page. However if I use the datascroller to goto another page, the mouseover effect is gone.

I've tried reRendering the table or the jQuery components, that didn't help with the problem at all.

Any suggestion on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but its worth a try. I have never used richfaces, but jQuery live events bind to all elements including future elements appended to the DOM.

```
<rich:jQuery selector="#dataTable tr" query="live('mouseover', function(){jQuery(this).addClass('active-row')})"/> 
<rich:jQuery selector="#dataTable tr" query="live('mouseout', function(){jQuery(this).removeClass('active-row')})"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've corrected the quotes in trying it out. 
The table rows on other pages doesn't seem to be stored on the page at all, until the page is loaded...I'm trying to have it reapply the jQuery function on load...